# cannot find Project**Name\ node_modules\react-native\packager\packager.js

Tags: android, react-native

React-Native for Android:
after `react-native init myProjectName`, cannot find `myProjectNam\node_modules\react-native\packager\packager.js`。
then cannot `node node_modules\react-native\packager\packager.js`
my phone and my computer connect the same wifi， but reloadJS have no effect, just a red screen in my phone.